# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln (\tan x)\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can I integrate $$\int_{0}^{\large\pi}\ln (\tan x)\,\text{dx}\;\;\;?$$

Comment: Is your function defined on the interval $[0,\pi]$ ?

Comment: $\ln(\tan(x))$ isn't defined for $x \in [\pi/2,\pi]$.

Comment: What do you guys mean, $\ln(\tan(x))$ is defined for $ \frac{\pi}{2} < x< \pi$, but it is not real-valued there.

Comment: the value is roughly 4.93i and the indefinite integral is possible but very difficult. It involves the polylogarithmic function. I am looking for an easier way.

Comment: I wonder if the integration limits are correct.

Comment: @Sasha: it's not obvious from the question that that is what he wants.

Comment: There is very great paper that I found of interest:http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/99/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01810298.pdf?auth66=1397941581_ddfc370917093328e5ca47852be2063c&ext=.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $\tan\left(\pi -x\right) = - \tan(x)$, and $\tan(x)$ is positive for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have:
$$
   \int_0^\pi \ln\left(\tan x\right) \mathrm{d}x = i \pi \int_0^{\pi/2} \mathrm{d} x + 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln\left(\tan x\right) \mathrm{d}x
$$
Furthermore, using $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right) = \frac{1}{\tan(x)}$ we see that
$$\begin{eqnarray}
  2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln\left(\tan x\right) \mathrm{d}x &=& \int_0^{\pi/2} \log\left(\tan x \right) \mathrm{d} x + \int_0^{\pi/2} \log\left(\tan y \right) \mathrm{d} y  \\
  &\stackrel{y=\pi/2 - x}{=}& \int_0^{\pi/2} \log\left(\tan x \right) \mathrm{d} x + \int_0^{\pi/2} \log\left(\frac{1}{\tan x} \right) \mathrm{d} x = 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$ 
Thus
$$
  \int_0^\pi \ln\left(\tan x\right) \mathrm{d}x = i \frac{\pi^2}{2}
$$

Comment: just curious, is it correct to solve it by noticing that $\log(\tan(x)) =\log ( \sin(x)) - \log( \cos(x)) = \Im(\log e^{ix})- \Re(\log e^{ix})= \Im(ix)- \Re(ix)$ and then integrating over $x \in [0, \pi]$?

Comment: @Alex No, because $\log(\sin(x)) = \log(\Im \mathrm{e}^{ix}) \not= \Im\left(\log \mathrm{e}^{i x}\right)$.

Comment: Thanks Sasha but i did not understand the line $\displaystyle\int_0^\pi \ln\left(\tan x\right) \mathrm{d}x = i \pi \int_0^{\pi/2} \mathrm{d} x + 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln\left(\tan x\right) \mathrm{d}x$

Comment: @juantheron $ \int_0^\pi \ln(\tan(x)) \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\tan(x)) \mathrm{d}x + \int_{\pi/2}^\pi \ln(\tan(y)) \mathrm{d}y$. Then change variables $y=\pi - x$, use $\tan\left(\pi - x\right) = -\tan(x)$. Now, since $\tan(x)>0$ for $0<x<\pi/2$, use $\ln(-\tan(x)) = i \pi + \ln(\tan(x))$.

Comment: thanks @sasha  but how come ln(-tan(x)) = i*pi+ ln(tan(x)) I can think  of -tan x = i^2 tan x only that's may not the case here is it?

Answer (score 6):

If looking for the real value only, it's enough to consider

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln (\tan x)dx$$
and let $x=\pi/2-y$
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln (\tan x)dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln (\cot x)dx$$
$$2I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln (1)dx$$
$$I=0$$

Comment: How do you go from $\ln(\cot x)$) to $\ln(1)$?