# Is it possible to approximate the integral $\int_{}^{}\ln (\tan x)\,dx$ in terms of elemantery function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I faced with this integral in a homework question, but i need elementary functions to do the necessary calculations. I thought about approximating [the value of integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772385/evaluation-of-integral-int-ln-tan-xdx?noredirect=1&lq=1) but i am not familiar with dilogarithm functions.

Comment: Make substitution $u=\tan (x) $ and $dx=du/\sec^2 (x)=du/(1+u^2)$. Use integration by parts to narrow it down to elementary functions plus $\int\arctan (u)/u du $ which can be put in terms of dilogarithm.

Comment: dilogirthm is not an elemantery function

Comment: Could always use a finite number of terms in the series representation of the dilogarithm, up till desired accuracy.

Comment: there is no finite number that is why i need elemantery functions. there is another variable that i need to look at that appears inside dilogarithm

Comment: probably this is not the way the lecturer want me to solve the problem but i just wondered if there are anyways.

Comment: I don't understand. Computing the first say $n $ terms of the dilogarithm would give you a good approximation and it would be in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: yeap you are right, i misunderstood you at first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my two cents. We have
$$\begin{aligned}
\int\ln(\tan(x))dx &= \int\frac{\ln(u)}{1+u^2}du \\
&= \ln(u)\arctan(u)-\int\frac{\arctan(u)}{u}du \\
&= \ln(u)\arctan(u)-\frac{1}{2} i\left(\text{Li}_2(-i u)-\text{Li}_2(i u)\right) +C\\
&= \ln(\tan(x))x-\frac{1}{2}i\left(\text{Li}_2(-i\tan(x))-\text{Li}_2(i\tan(x))\right) +C \\
&\approx \ln(\tan(x))x-\frac{1}{2}i\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\left[\frac{(-i\tan(x))^k-(i\tan(x))^k}{k^2}\right]\right)+C \\
&= \ln(\tan(x))x+i\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\frac{(i\tan(x))^{2k+1}}{k^2}\right]\right)+C \\
&= \ln(\tan(x))x+\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\frac{i^{2(k+1)}\tan(x)^{2k+1}}{k^2}\right]+C \\
&= \ln(\tan(x))x+\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\frac{(-1)^{k+1}\tan(x)^{2k+1}}{k^2}\right]+C
\end{aligned}$$
Which approximates the antiderivative with elementary functions. Here $n$ is just some finite integer you choose and your error will be less than
$$\left|\frac{\tan(x)^{2n+1}}{(n+1)^2}\right|$$
since this is the first term in the (previously infinite) alternating series that we neglect.