# integrate$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\tan(x)\,dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

integrate$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\tan(x)\,dx$ there is a discontinutity so I break it at $\pi/2$

$$\begin{align}&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\tan(x)\,dx+ \int_{\pi}^{\pi/2}\tan(x)\,dx\\
=&[\log(\sec x)]^{\pi/2} _{0} +[\log(\sec x)]^{\pi} _{\pi/2}\\
=&\lim_{x\to\pi/2^{-}}\log(\sec x)+\iota\pi -  \lim_{x\to\pi/2^{+}}\log(\sec x)\\
=&\lim_{h\to0}\log(\csc h)+\iota\pi -  \lim_{h\to0}\log(-\csc h)\\
=&\lim_{h\to0}\log \left( \frac{\csc h}{\csc h} \right) +\iota\pi -  \log(-1)\\
=&\lim_{h\to0}\log \left( \frac{\csc h}{\csc h} \right) +\iota\pi - \iota\pi \\
=&\lim_{h\to0}\log \left( \frac{\csc h}{\csc h} \right) \\
=&\lim_{h\to0}\log(1)\\
=&0\end{align}$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln (\tan x)\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285901/how-to-evaluate-int-0-pi-ln-tan-x-dx)

Comment: Not a duplicate, linked one has ln(tan) not just tan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integral diverges because as you have calculated, you are dealing with $\sec(x)$ which diverges at $\pi/2$  $$[\log(|\sec (x)|)]^{\pi/2} _{0} +[\log(|\sec (x)|)]^{\pi} _{\pi/2}$$

diverges because both limits diverge to infinity.